# Entity Framework Migrations - The underlying provider does not support the type 'nvarchar(max)'

Tags: mysql, migration, localdb

I am converting my C# asp site to use a mysql db instead of the local db that the project is first built with.  I am using two dbs, one for the built in account functionality, and one for the functionality that I have added.

The problem I have is that when the second db is seeding, I get the following message:
The underlying provider does not support the type 'nvarchar(max)'.

I'm assuming this is due to MS syntax that works with the .mdf db, but doesn't work with MySQL?

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: I think this comes from when you set up string type variables in your model but don't give the string an explicit length.  Works fine for SQLServer variants, but breaks MySQL.

I suspect the solution is as simple as giving all your string type elements in your models an explicit length, and then all should be fine.

Have not had reason to test this yet, but will do so and feed back.